# Cloud Flare, R2, how to upload images?

Tags: cloudflare

Cloud Flare, R2, how to upload images??

I`m new to Cloud Flare world,

and I can upload the pictures by dragging but

how to upload image using coding? from application??

do I have to use "WORKERS" <-- things?

Comment: It rather depends where you want to access the storage from, have you read the docs? https://developers.cloudflare.com/r2/data-access/

Comment: @Jodrell Yup I read them I needed public storage, and access was successful, but I am confused with "uploading" right now, how to upload image to R2 storage??? and I do not use S3

Comment: Do you use `npm`/`yarn` ?

Comment: @Jodrell Yes I can use node js.

Comment: I want to close this question

Answer (score 5):

Hey I got stuck with this for two days and was not able to figure it out. So I wanted to share my solution.

**My Goal** 
I was developing a software for collecting data from our end users to get information from them. But they needed an image to be submitted for us to verify them, that is why I needed to have a form to enable users to upload their file and an API endpoint to store their file.

**Solution** 
I set up an Cloudflare worker as an API since it connects well with R2, you just have to define it in your worker settings.

**My Cloudflare worker script & Example form for allowing users to upload files**

```js
// CLOUDFLARE WORKER SCRIPT
// ------------------------
export default {
  async fetch(request, env) {
    const corsHeaders = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Max-Age': '86400',
    };

    // Check for preflight request from the browser.
    if (request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      return new Response(null, {
        headers: {
          ...corsHeaders,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': request.headers.get(
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers'
          ),
        }
      });
    } else {
      // Handle actual request and store image to bucket.
      const { headers } = request;
      
      // Key is date now since we want keys to be unique. 
      const key = Date.now();
      await env.MY_BUCKET.put(key, request.body, {
        httpMetadata: {
          contentType: headers.get('content-type')
        }
      });

      return new Response('success!', {
        headers: {
          ...corsHeaders,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': request.headers.get(
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers'
          ),
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Upload Images with Cloudflare R2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="image">Select image to upload:</label>
      <input type="file" name="image" id="image" /><br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>

    <script>
      async function uploadImage(file) {
        fetch('https://<YOUR-OWN-WORKER>.workers.dev', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': file.type
          },
          body: file
        })
          .then((response) => response.text())
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((error) => console.error(error));
      }

      const image = document.getElementById('image');
      const onSelectFile = () => uploadImage(image.files[0]);
      image.addEventListener('change', onSelectFile, false);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh man, thank you. I wasted a day for it too..

Comment: How do we select and upload multiple files at once using this approach

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded files to r2 successfully with [rclone](https://rclone.org/).

### Configure rclone

First, [install rclone](https://rclone.org/install/) on our PC.

And then create a `rclone.conf` file under the path `~/.config/rclone/`.

```
[r2]
type = s3
provider = Cloudflare
access_key_id = <ACCESS_KEY>
secret_access_key = <SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
region = auto
endpoint = https://<ACCOUNT_ID>.r2.cloudflarestorage.com
acl = private
```

- [r2]: A custom name(an alias) for storage service. We need to use it to operate files.
- type = s3: The type of file operation API. R2 supports the S3 standard protocol.
- provider = Cloudflare: The storage provider ID. You could use `man rclone` to get the supported providers.
- access_key_id: You need to create a token with edit permission on the R2 console.
- secret_access_key: Same as above.
- endpoint: The url that rclone uses to operate files. To get the account id on the top-right of R2 homepage.

### Usage

run `rclone lsf r2:` to see your buckets and `rclone lsf r2:my-bucket` to show the file list within a bucket.

> Especially notice the last symbol `:`

upload a file:

```bash
rclone copy /path/to/file r2:my-bucket
```

Comment: aws js sdk was the best solution